# What does these below code mean?

Tags: html, css

```
 border-color:#4d90fe!important
```

What does the above line mean in html/css. I have come acrossed these styling , on google, facebook and many more websites(source code). what !important indicates ? Could anyone clear these question,

```
1) when to use % or em 
2) when to use px
```

When I saw google page source I have found it using % sometimes and px sometimes. Mostly for padding, margin borders, width , it used px and  for width and height it used % and at certain times.Im in a confusion to use px and %, Could anyone clear me when to use px and when to use % or em.

Comment: Please separate your questions. Also, what *!important* means is covered in every CSS tutorial you could ever find. :)

Comment: **[W3C explanation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)** about the !important keyword.

Comment: I didnt find it on w3schools.com sorry to say that ! I found it somewhere else but unable to grasp the concept Thats why i asked it here for a good explaination!

Comment: @niko: just as a sidenote to w3schools, lake a look at http://w3fools.com/

Comment: why people say w3schools is not good one but what i find over there really works on every browser! Should I ignore using w3schools but I find w3schools is much easy to learn than anyother

Comment: read on w3fools - a lot of things might be ok on w3schools, but there are also a lot of failures oder solutions using bad practices. it might be better to ignore w3schools or, at least, countercheck other sources to be sure what you're reading/learning isn't totally wrong or outdated stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [google](http://www.google.com) this is very easy to answer on your own in less that 2 minutes:

- [!important](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/) (searching for `css !important`)
  in short: `!important` sets the css-rule to highest priority/precedence, overwriting all other rules specifying another value for the same attribute
- [explanation of units](http://www.elated.com/articles/css-units/) (searching for `css units`)
  in short: `px` means pixel, `em` refers to the actual font-height and `%` is percentage - almost self-explaining

Answer (score 1):

% is when you want a scaling site.  For things to be a percentage of one another, for example:

```
<div style="width:100%;">
    <div style="width:50%"></div>
</div>
```

px is for when you want to assign the exact pixel size of an attribute, such as width:

```
<div style="width:100px;">
    <div style="width:50px"></div>
</div>
```

The above two examples are not the same thing.  The one with % will fill the parent (the element that it is contained in), while the other will only be as big as the px (pixel) specified size.

**Added after comment:** Scaling means that if as the size of the screen changes user by user, the content will adjust itself to the size of the browser window (with different monitor resolutions for example).

Attribute is probably better defined as a property.  A property of a `<div>` for example can be width, height, color, etc...

Comment: Could you please elabrote it more so that I can understand I dont really know what is scaling and attribute as I newly started learning HTML5 and css on google

Comment: I find snippets on google even the hardy ones but sometimes i dont understand the real working of it, the real worth to programmers is understanding the concept rather than copying the code found on google!so please help me!

Answer (score 1):

As for the !important statement, if you don't know, CSS is interpreted, which means (among other things) read from top to bottom, so, if you define for example:

```
.one { border-color: #000000; }
.two { border-color: #ffffff; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="one two"></div>
```

This div will have #ffffff as border color.
Now if you have:

```
.one { border-color: #000000 !important; }
.two { border-color: #ffffff; }
```

And the same div as before the border color will be #000000. Because of the !important that first definition take precedence.

You can read more about !important here (for example): http://www.yellowjug.com/web-design/the-importance-of-important-in-css/

As for the usage of em/% and px, Musaab response is pretty self explanatory.